# Running vs Cycling vs Stairs

Tags: running, calories, body-fat, bicycling, stairs

What is best way to burn calories? Some of my friends do cycling and I do running.  I have seen statistics from fitness App and I found that I am burning more calories then them if we keep distance constant. However If I do stairs I feel more tired than running if we keeep time as constant. 
My question is which one is fastest and efficient way to loose fat and gain strength.

Answer (score 2):

A lot depends on the intensity and the duration of a training. You'll find lots of articles on the internet about this. Just to give you an example I've placed 2 links below which compare running & running stairs.

- [Ask the Personal trainer](https://www.weightwatchers.com/util/art/index_art.aspx?tabnum=1&art_id=11681&sc=128)
- [Running vs Stairs](http://healthyliving.azcentral.com/burns-calories-running-climbing-stairs-7572.html)

Running on stairs does in fact burn more calories than running on the flat. But the question you should be asking yourself: **Can I run as long on stairs as on the flat?**

An example in my case:

- I can run (easy pace) for 90min without problems/excessive fatigue, which burns according to my garmin between the 700 and 1050 kcal
- I can only run/walk for 30min on stairs in the gym (before i'm bored out of my mind). This burns according to the device around the 300-500kcal.

In my case running would be more beneficial.

**Remark:** My personal advice (if your goal is to lose weight) is to start with a maintainable(healthy) diet combined with some light sports to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Depends entirely on intensity.

Interval training on a treadmill for 50 minutes will burn more calories than a steady bike ride for 50 minutes. All of the exercised have their benefits and drawbacks in terms of impact to your body but it is generally accepted that a cross trainer has the least impact on your joints.

Comment: Agree about the intensity of workout , I also found running cause makes damaging shock waves in bone and shock waves get worst on asphalt . After 8 km of run on road pain begin to develop on bone between knee and ankles.

Comment: @HiteshSahu - You probably have worn out shoes. Barring preexisting injuries, that is the biggest reason for pain starting in the middle of a run. (Other than running too far for fitness level).